# Python Package Malware Ztz

Tags: python, django, pip

When I try to do `pip install requirements.txt` of a [basic requirements package for django](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template/blob/master/requirements.txt), the following malware runs:

```
Collecting requirements.txt
  Using cached requirements_txt-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ztz (from requirements.txt)
  Using cached ztz-0.1.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: ztz, requirements.txt
  Running setup.py install for ztz ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/[user redacted]/inventory-barcode/inventoryenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/q9/124ns0sn68d1gkhlps1t60s80000gn/T/pip-build-nrl9xijr/ztz/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/q9/124ns0sn68d1gkhlps1t60s80000gn/T/pip-zthn0_6m-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/[user redacted]/inventory-barcode/inventoryenv/include/site/python3.6/ztz:
    running install
    [+] It looks like you try to install ztz without checking it.
    [-] is that alright?
    [*] Please visit http://evilpackage.fatezero.org/
    [/] Aborting installation.

    ----------------------------------------
```

The [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ztz/0.1.1) is supposedly intended to show people the dangers of installing typo'd packages, but it's obnoxious and unwelcome, and supposedly puts the user info online for public shaming. How can I get rid of it and prevent it from hijacking pip?

Comment: Remove ztz from requirements?

Comment: You invoked `pip install` incorrectly; you forgot the `-r`. Without it, `pip` is installing the package named `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, dirn. That sounds like a terrible oversight in the design if that's the case.

Comment: @BojanKogoj ztz is not in requirements